# Outlier detection approach with smaller datasets

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, comparison, outliers

I have a python function that takes a list of smaller images `boxes` (represented as arrays) and the whole image `img` in as a parameter and finds outliers. The outliers will either be significantly brighter or darker than the other images in the list, but darker is the more common case.

```py
def find_outliers(boxes, img):
    means = [np.mean(box['src']) for box in boxes]
    asc = sorted(means)
    q1, q3 = np.percentile(asc, [25,75])
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lower = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
    upper =  q3 + (1.5 * iqr)

    # print('thresholds:', lower, upper)
    return list(filter(lambda x: np.mean(x['src']) < lower or np.mean(x['src']) > upper, boxes))
```

This method allows me to create thresholds based on the image, instead of coming up with hard values, which is ideal in my situation. There are 3 problems I need to address if I continue this approach.

1. Sometimes the brighter/darker images outnumber the normal images. These images have extreme values which biases my outlier method into thinking they are normal.
2. Sometimes the number of `boxes` is very small (3 or 4). This makes it hard for this method to find an adequate lower and upper bound.
3. The lower and upper bounds can be negative, but all of my values will be greater than or equal to 0.

Is there a statistical approach that is better suited for this type of problem? Is there a different way to establish a threshold values based on the image?

Note: I also have tried the standard deviation outlier approach but this one isn't suitable in this scenario.

Comment: You said *create thresholds based on the image*, but you don't use `img` in your function? I understand that the boxes come from `img` (are subimages of `img`). Is this correct?

Comment: thats correct. I have not used img yet but if there is a way that I could I just wanted the community to know that it was possible.

Comment: so I would compare the boxes with the percentiles of the img; if you like I could write it as an answer so you could try it.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, please do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than finding outliers in the list of boxes, we calculate the lower and upper boundaries *with respect to the whole image* and any boxes with average gray values outside these boundaries are considered as outliers:

```
def find_outliers(boxes, img):
    q1, q3 = np.percentile(img, [25,75])
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lower = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
    upper =  q3 + (1.5 * iqr)

    # print('thresholds:', lower, upper)
    return list(filter(lambda x: np.mean(x['src']) < lower or np.mean(x['src']) > upper, boxes))
```

Comment: The approach is helpful but introduced a lot of false positives. This is because there are boxes of the image that are dark, but still very similar compared to the other boxes, meaning  they are not outliers.

Comment: hmm, maybe you could tune the iqr factor, e.g. 2 instead of 1.5. But in the end you'll have to decide if you need outliers with respect to the image as a whole (my answer) of outliers with respect to the list of boxes (your original). I'm afraid I don't see any practical way to combine both approaches.

Comment: Yeah I'm with you. Might have to run another direction with it.

Comment: I asked the same question of Stack Exchange for statistics and got pretty good insight: 

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420220/outliers-of-small-dataset/420250#420250